# Rails - Redcloth, how do I convert exsiting wysiwyg crap html?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, redcloth

I've seen the light, I'm converting my site over to [RedCloth](http://redcloth.org/) to use the wonderful textile markup.

Problem is, I have a couple years worth of html content in my database that is not textile markup. How do I convert that into textile? Is there a non-manual way?

If no, when outputting content, should I check for html, if present then don't use RedCloth?

example:

```
// not sure of best way to check if a string has html
if (@content.description has html)
    <%= @content.description.html_safe %>
else
    <%= RedCloth.new(@content.description).to_html %>
end
```

What is the ruby way on this? Help a newb! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this: http://clothred.rubyforge.org/

And this: https://github.com/jystewart/html2textile

And this: https://github.com/mattt/pricetag

**edit**

I went with html2textile. I installed it using the instruction from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4833365/rails-how-to-use-a-plugin-from-github-how-to-install-utilize-etc) I asked.

I then created a task in /lib/tasks/app.rake called textile_ize. It looks like so:

```
namespace :db do
  desc "Convert html to textile on desc columns"
  task :textile_ize => :environment do
    puts "Starting Desc"

    contents = Content.all
    contents.each do |c|
                    #desc
        parser = HTMLToTextileParser.new
        parser.feed(c.desc)
        c.desc_textile = parser.to_textile
        c.save
    end

    puts "Finished with Desc"

end
```

I could then run `rake db:textile_ize` and poof, done. I actually added an additional column to store the textile and create html from the textile with `:before_save`. That looked like this (in my model):

```
before_save :textile_ize

# convert textile to html
def textile_ize
    self.desc = RedCloth.new(self.desc_textile).to_html     
end
```

Hope this helps someone out there!

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Rdiscount for markup parsing , it work both with html and textile input .
I suppose textile allow html , infact if i put **strong tag** in this editor it's work!

what happens if you simple parse both html and textile with redcloth?

```
<%= RedCloth.new(@content.description).to_html %>
```

Comment: It adds double the spaces because it's also detects line breaks as paragraphs :/