# Rails - how to use a plugin from github (how to install, utilize, etc)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I'm trying to install a couple of different plugins for my rails 3 app. I cd to '/vendor/plugins/', then type `git clone the_git_src_url`.

I see the files in the /vendor/plugins/ directory. However when I try to use any of the tags provided by the plugin I get

```
uninitialized constant ContentsController::HTMLToTextileParser
```

[PriceTag](https://github.com/mattt/pricetag) and [html2textile](https://github.com/thickpaddy/html2textile) are the two plugins I'm trying to use. This is what triggers the error above: `<%= PriceTag.html_to_textile(@content.desc) %>`

I'm working in development, I've tried to restart the server. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`html2textile` is a Ruby gem, not a Rails plugin. To install a gem to be used in a Rails 3 app you can use builder adding the new gem in your Gemfile.

```
gem 'yourgem', :git=>'git://yourpath.git'
```

i.e.

```
gem 'html2textile', :git=>'git://github.com/thickpaddy/html2textile.git'
```

This will say that your application *needs* that gem to work; running `bundle install` will check if all the gems needed by your app are installed and will install the missing ones.

---

If you like manual labor and the gem of your interest is not available with the usual `gem install yourgem`, you can install it checking out the source code from the repository and building the gem by yourself.

To build `html2textile`:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/thickpaddy/html2textile.git
$ cd html2textile/
$ gem build html2textile.gemspec
$ gem install html2textile-1.0.0.jgp.gem
$ gem list | grep html2
html2textile (1.0.0.jgp)
```

Now you can require `html2textile` in you Rails app or in your plain Ruby scripts.

```
$ irb
> require 'rubygems'
=> true
> require 'html2textile'
=> true
```

`pricetag` can be handled in the same way.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using [bundler](http://gembundler.com/rails3.html) with rails3.  Add this to your Gemfile:

```
gem 'html2textile', :git=>'git://github.com/thickpaddy/html2textile.git'
```

then

`bundle install`

Answer (score 0):

lbz is right about html2textile.

Other plugins are installed as follows:

**Rails2:**

```
script/plugin install <source>
```

**Rails3:**

```
rails plugin install <source>
```

`<source>` would normally be sth. like git://github.com/xxx/yyy.git